# Buttons jumping around on page load

Tags: html, css

please have a look how my buttons are jumping around when each page loads.  How do I preload the relative positioning / fb api to prevent this from happening on each page?

http://kundalinilive.com

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook `iframe` is inserted to the DOM after the fact and its size has an effect on the positioning of the buttons.  You can fix this just by adding the width/height created by the `<iframe>` to the existing `.fb-like` div

```
.fb-like {
    height: 25px;
    width: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep them invisible using css:

```
display:none
```

And show them on page load (using jquery):

```
$(function(){
     $('.topBar').fadeIn(); 
});
```